# Matlab vector to its binary representation

Tags: matlab, vector, binary

I have a vector like A: 1 3 7 8
I would like to construct a binary vecor such as B (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
                                                   (1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use just indexing:

```
B = zeros(1, max(A));
B(A) = 1;
```

Or use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

```
B = full(sparse(1, A, 1));
```

These approaches don't require arithmetical operations, and thus may be faster than previous answers.

Comment: +1 - This to me is the most elegant solution... and the one I would have come up with myself

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
binA = sum( de2bi(2.^(A-1)) , 1 ) 

binA =

     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     1
```

Comment: +1. If you don't have the Communications Toolbox (which includes `de2bi`): use `sum( dec2bin(2.^(A-1))-'0' , 1 )`

Comment: I have octave in front of me now, and it doesn't work when you have zeros in the vector `A`, does it work in MATLAB?

Comment: @vsoftco A `0` value in `A` won't work in Matlab... and it's not meaningful either, is it? Matlab indexing starts at `1`

Comment: @LuisMendo, that's why I asked, I had the feeling that the OP wants to transform in binary a decimal number represented as a vector in MATLAB, so in principle you will have `0`'s inside, isn't it?

Comment: @vsoftco From the OP example, the purpose seems to be: set to one the bits indicated by `A`, leave the rest as zero

Comment: @LuisMendo Ahhh ok, I was wandering why the binary representation of 1378 was not the one appearing in the example :) Thanks, the title was misleading.

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, a much better title would perhaps have been "opposite of 'find' function"

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the vector to an integer (base 10),

```
d = sum(A(:).*(10.^[numel(A)-1: -1: 0])(:))
```

then convert `d` to binary using

```
b = de2bi(d)
```

You can then extract as many bits as you want from `b`

Comment: Probably that final `(:)`. You can't chain indexings in Matlab as you do in Octave

Comment: Also, MATLAB's method is [`dec2bin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html), while Octave's is `de2bi`.  `de2bi` can be used if you have the Communications Toolbox (a là Luis Mendo).

Comment: @rayryeng, no, MATLAB has both, `dec2bin` is standard, `de2bi` comes in `Communication System Toolbox`.

Comment: @vsoftco - I corrected myself before you put your message up :)